# Only keep part before the 2th pattern in R

Tags: r, split, gsub

How could I remove everything before the `second pattern` occurence in a dataframe using R?

I used:

```
for (i in 1:length(df1)){
  df1[, i]<- gsub(".*_", "",df1[, i])
}
```

But I guess there is a better way to apply that for all the dataframe?

Here is an exemple of a value in the dataframe:

```
name_000004_A_B_C
name_00003_C_D
```

and get

```
A_B_C
C_D
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: By second pattern you mean the second underscore?

Comment: @tmfmnk yes the second underscore '_' and if you could explain me the steps of the code as well it would be amazing :)

Comment: Try `stringr::str_split_fixed(x,"_",3)[,3]`.

Comment: Or `sub("^[^_]+_[^_]+_(.+)", "\\1", x)` perhaps.

Comment: @markus why so complicated?: `sub("^[^_]+_[^_]+_", "", x)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x <- c("name_000004_A_B_C", "name_00003_C_D")
gsub("(name_[0-9]*_)(.*)", "\\2", x)
##[1] "A_B_C" "C_D"
```

More generalised:

```
gsub("([a-z0-9]*_[a-z0-9]*_)(.*)", "\\2", x)
#[1] "A_B_C" "C_D"
```

The global substitution takes two matching group patterns into consideration, first is the pattern `(name_[0-9]*_)` and the second is whatever comes after. It keeps the second matching group. Hope this hepls!

Comment: This is less "generalized" than other solutions, maybe just more easy to read though.

Comment: Although regex and "easy to read" never go well together anyway.

Comment: again more efficient: `sub("^name_[0-9]*_", "", x)` and `sub("^[a-z0-9]*_[a-z0-9]*_", "", x)`